# evaluating limits using polar coordinates

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

For the following limit, why can you not convert to polar form and evaluate e.g.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}\frac{(x^3+y^3)}{(x^2-y^2)}\to\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r(\sin^3(t)+\cos^3(t))}{\sin^2(t)-\cos^2(t)} = 0$$

However the real limit does not exist. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit cannot be zero in polar coordinates because for $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $t=0$ we have different results as $r \to 0$

For the limit to exists in polar coordinates,the result must be independent of $t$ as $r \to 0$

Comment: doesn't r just make the numerator always zero?

Comment: Yes it does but you have also the denominator on the scene..and for t=π/4 we have a problem.